# Shifting columns of an array to the left

Tags: python, arrays

My goal is to shift the columns of an array `B` `k` positions to the left. Assume `B` is of the shape `(n,n)`. Then of course, the columns from `n` to `n-k` have to replaced with some new entries. But this shouldn't be of importance here. What does work is the following:

```py
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n-k):
      B[i][j]  = B[i][j+k]
```

I wonder if there is a faster and simpler method. Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you were using your matrix in column-major order (i.e. using `i` as column index), much less copies would be needed

```
for j in range(n-k):
   B[i] = B[i+k]
```

in this case only the reference to the column is copied

Answer (score 0):

You could use subscripts:

```
B = B[k:] + newValues
```

or, if you want to keep the array size and manipulate the original positions afterward:

```
B[:k] = B[k:2*k]
```

*note that, in this last approach, you must have 2k <= n otherwise you won't have enough elements to fill the left side of the array*